# comma inside double quote in comma separated csv,

Tags: unix

How to cut the value inside the double quotes and seperated with comma.
Eg.

```
Number               Name
"12,13"      ,       "Ram"
"32,15,21"   ,       "Krishna"
```

I need the output like :

```
Number

12,13
32,15,21
```

I am using the command `cut -d "," -f1`, but not getting the expected value.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sed 's/"//g; s/ .*//' foo.csv
```

result

```
Number
12,13
32,15,21
```

- remove all `"`
- remove all after first space

Answer (score 0):

```
> perl -lane '$F[0]=~s/"//g;print $F[0]' your_file
```

Above should work.

```
> cat temp
Number               Name
"12,13"      ,       "Ram"
"32,15,21"   ,       "Krishna"
> perl -lane '$F[0]=~s/"//g;print $F[0]' temp
Number
12,13
32,15,21
>
```